Trying to install openai-whisper via Poetry, but getting "No module named 'whisper'"
Hello all: I am trying to add openai-whisper via Poetry. I have tried many steps including adding the git to pyproject.toml dependencies.
[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.12"
numpy = "^2.1.2"
pyaudio = "^0.2.14"
requests = "^2.32.3"
openai = "^1.52.0"
pyperclip = "^1.9.0"
scrubadub = "^2.0.1"
speechrecognition = "^3.10.4"
openai-whisper = { git = "https://github.com/openai/whisper.git", rev = "v20231117" }

[build-system]
requires = ["poetry-core"]
build-backend = "poetry.core.masonry.api"

Output:
    import whisper
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'whisper'

Is there any other way to install openai-whisper to my Poetry virtual environment?
